# how I can install packages inside a running docker container and packages take effect without recreating the container?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, volume

I am running `docker compose up` which consists of multiple containers on of which is python 3.*  and all the containers have volumes attached to them.
also I have already created requirements.txt file
I have entered python container and install x packages then I did
`pip freeze > requirements.txt`
I then I stoped the containers and restart the containers again, but python container didn't start and the log says  `modules x is not found`, so what I did is that O deleted the container and created a new one and it worked,
my questions is, Is there any way to not deleting the container (I think its over kill)
but some-who still able to manage installing packages in the container?

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gettext

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/server
COPY src/requirements.txt /var/www/server/

WORKDIR /var/www/server
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8100
ENTRYPOINT sleep 3 && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8100
```

Comment: pip freeze < requirements.txt should be pip freeze >  requirements.txt right?

Comment: "Deleting and recreating the container" is essentially just "stopping and restarting the process".  It's totally normal to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your project source files into the container during build and within in it run the `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Below is an example to give you an idea:

```
--- Other build commands follow
WORKDIR /usr/src/service
COPY ./service . # Here, I am moving everything of the service folder/module into WORKDIR within docker
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
-- Other build commands follow.
```

Finally, you will use docker-compose build service to build the define service in the docker-compose.yml pointing to the Dockerfile in the build context.

```
...
build:
  context: .
    dockerfile: service/Dockerfile
...
```

Comment: this is good and what they should be doing, but I'd quickly note that it's usually best to bring in just the dependency needs before installing them and the rest of the project later to avoid rebuilding on every code change!

Comment: I agree this part, and that is why it was mentioned as Other build commands follow assuming the OP has the idea of them already :)

Answer (score -1):

Broadly, set up your Dockerfile such that you need to do the least-changing and most time-costly work first

```
FROM FOO
RUN get os-level and build dependencies
COPY only exactly files needed to identify dependencies
RUN install dependencies that takes a long time
RUN install more frequently-changing dependencies
COPY rest of your wanted content
ENTRYPOINT define me
```

as [**@coldly** says in their Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72549729/4541045), write your dependencies into a requirements file and install them during the container build!